# If $f$ is a quadratic and $f(x)>0\;\forall x$, and $g= f + f' + f''$, prove $g(x)>0\; \forall x$

Tags: calculus

If $f(x)$ is a quadratic expression such that $f(x)>0\;\forall x\in\mathbb{R},$ and if $g(x)=f(x)+f'(x)+f''(x),$

Then prove that $g(x)>0\; \forall \; x\in \mathbb{R}$.

$\bf{My\; Trial \; Solution::}$ If $f(x)>0\;\forall x\in \mathbb{R}$. Then function $f(x)$ has Minimum value .

Let Minimum occur at $x=x_{0}$. Then $f(x)_{Min} = f(x_{0})>0$

Now Given $g(x) = f(x)+f'(x)+f''(x)$. Then $g'(x) = f'(x)+f''(x)+f'''(x).$

Now at $x=x_{0}\;\;,$ Value of $g(x_{0}) = f'(x_{0})+f''(x_{0})+f'''(x_{0}) = 0+f''(x_{0})+f'''(x_{0})$

Now I did not understand How can i solve after that,

Help me

Thanks

Comment: Not true for arbitrary functions, eg $f(x) =2 + 1/6 \sin 6 x$. The title should perhaps mention it applies only to quadratic polynomials.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose $f(x)=x^2+ax+b$ with $b=f(0)>0$ and $a^2<4b$. Then,
$$
g(x)=x^2+(a+2)x+(2+a+b).
$$
We note that $g(0)=2+a+b=1+f(1)>0$ and
$$
(a+2)^2-4(2+a+b)=a^2+4a+4-8-4a-4b=(a^2-4b)-4<0
$$
so $g$ is never $0$ for real $x$. You now can infer that $g$ is always positive.

The more general case $f(x)=C(x^2+ax+b)$ is the same. It just adds the constant $C>0$ to everything.

Comment: Is there anything more to it as it is the case with all quadratic polynomials ?

Answer (score 4):

Since $f$ is positive, we can complete the square and write $f(x)=a(x-h)^2+k$ with $a,k > 0$. Then 
\begin{eqnarray}
g(x)&=&a(x-h)^2+k+2a(x-h)+2a\\
&=&a(x-h)(x-h+2)+k+2a\\
&=&a[(x-h+1)^2-1]+k+2a\\
&=&a(x-h+1)^2+k+a
\end{eqnarray}
is a similarly positive quadratic expression.

ETA: A goofy alternative way of phrasing this would be to say:

- Since $f$ is quadratic, all its higher-order derivatives vanish.
- So, if $D$ is the differential operator, then $f(x)+f'(x)+\frac{f''(x)}{2}=(e^Df)(x)=f(x+1)$.
- So $g(x)=f(x+1)+\frac{f''(x)}{2}$. But if $f$ is quadratic and everywhere positive, then its second derivative must be positive; thus $g$ is everywhere positive.

Answer (score 1):

Without loss of generality, we can assume that $f(x)= (x-a)^2 + b^2$.

Note that $g$ is also a quadratic polynomial. We find the critical point of $g$.

$$
g'(x) = f'(x) +  f''(x)$$

Note also that third derivative of $f$ is zero.

Then we see that the critical point is $x=a-1$, and also it gives the minimum value of $g$.

Plug in the value to $g$, then we have

$$
g(a-1) = f(a-1) + g'(a-1) = f( a-1) > 0.$$

Therefore $g(x)>0$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$.